# Get the value of a span in a Textblock

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock

After converting a SVG to XAML I got a lot of textblocks looking like this :

```
<TextBlock xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" FontSize="10"  Foreground="#FF000000"Name="text324947"><Span  FontSize="10">79</Span></TextBlock>
```

Now the question is : how can I access the Text inside the span ? The Text Property of my TextBlock is Empty.

Thanks

Comment: This property doesn't seem to exist =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`Inlines` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.inlines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (see link).

Given your XAML, you may do this:

```
TextBlock tb = this.txt
Span span = (Span) tb.Inlines.FirstInline;
Run run = (Run) span.Inlines.FirstInline;
string text = run.Text;
```

Comment: Thanks it sounds like a good idea, I'll try to find out how to use it

Comment: I just needed to explicitly cast to (Span) and (Run) on lines 2 and 3. Works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: That's right @Joey sorry I missed it. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Span is used to group other inline flow content elements together  so no property such as Text or Content is directly exposed

here how you can get  the text  inside the span inline element

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Name="txtBlock">  <Span Name="span">test</Span> </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
         string s= (span.Inlines.ToArray()[0] as Run).Text;
       // or just try this 
         string s2= ((txtBlock.Inlines.FirstInline as Span).Inlines.FirstInline as Run).Text;  
    }
```